# WP display different custom fields in different pages

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

In WP admin/'edit page' (not in rendered page), how can I display different custom fields (meta-datas) in different pages?

Answer (score 1):

Check out a plugin called [Meta Box](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/meta-box/).

> Meta Box plugin provides an API to easily implement custom meta boxes in editing pages (add new/edit post) in WordPress. It works with custom post types and supports various field types.